# Pass parameters to event in a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling, parameter-passing

I have loaded some Picturebox with image location from database, I would like to pass parameters (price and name) to click event handler in a loop

code looks like this:

```
private void Caisse_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int repetition = 0;
        int rep = 1;
        textMontant.Text = mont;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "select desig_prd,prix_prd ,image from Produit ",con);

       using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           while (reader1.Read())
           {
               if (repetition % 3== 0)
                   repetition = 0;

               PictureBox p = new PictureBox();

              p.Click += new System.EventHandler(P_Click(sender, 
              new MyEventArgs { design = reader1["desig_prd"].ToString(), prix = (float)reader1["prix_prd"] }));

               p.ImageLocation = reader1["image"].ToString();

              p.Height = 100;
              p.Width = 160;
              p.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4+ repetition * 150, (int)(rep/4)*130+4);

               panel1.Controls.Add(p);
               repetition++;
               rep++;
           }


       }   
    }
```

On click under picturebox i would like to pass 2 parameters (price:reader1["prix_prd"] and product name: reader1["desig_prd"]), don't forget they are in a loop!
i know that

```
 p.Click += new System.EventHandler(P_Click(sender, 
              new MyEventArgs { design = reader1["desig_prd"].ToString(), prix = (float)reader1["prix_prd"] }));
```

triggers an error "event name expected" but how to pass parameters to event in a loop?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass custom arguments to `Click` event handlers, because you're not the one who raises the event...

However, you can use an anonymous method or lambda expression to specify a handler that captures the necessary data:

```
var design = reader1["desig_prd"].ToString();
var prix = (float)reader1["prix_prd"];
p.Click += (sender1, e1) => SomeMethod(design, prix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda to close over the relevant variables:

```
string design = reader1["desig_prd"].ToString();
fload prix = (float)reader1["prix_prd"];
p.Click += (s, args) => P_Click(p,
    new MyEventArgs
    {
        design = design,
        prix = prix,
    });
```

Comment: this error occur "Attempt to call MetaData invalid when the reader is closed". in p.Click += (s, args) => P_Click(p, new MyEventArgs
    {
        design = design,
        prix = prix,
    });

Comment: Well you're not accessing the reader on that line of code, nor should you ever need to access the reader withing `P_Click`, so you must not be showing the exact code that you're using.